# Rails 4 - how to fetch all "belongs_to" for an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, belongs-to

I have this scheme:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
end
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

I fetch all cars that has been added between certain dates, like:

```
@cars = Car.where("... from-to condition ...")
```

What I am trying to get: a unique list of all owners from `@cars`, in the best way like `owners.email` + `owners.id`. I've tried to do

```
puts @cars.owner.pluck(:id, :email).inspect
```

But this results into following error:

```
undefined method `owner' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::...
```

How to get a list of all owners of the selected cars?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're coming at this from the wrong side. You're trying to find `Owners`, so start there:

`Owner`

Now you add a joins, since you're trying to find `owners` whose `cars` meet some criteria:

`Owner.joins(:car)`

then add your where:

`Owner.joins(:car).where(cars: {>your conditions<})`

then add a `distinct` since in some cases you can have an owner who has multiple cars that match:

`Owner.joins(:car).where(cars: {>your conditions<}).distinct`

And then if you just want the id/email, you can pluck:

`Owner.joins(:car).where(cars: {>your conditions<}).distinct.pluck("owner.id, owner.email")`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
puts @cars.joins(:owner).pluck("owner.id, owner.email")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Car.where("... from-to condition ...").joins(:owner).distinct.pluck('owners.id', 'owners.email')
```

EDIT: Fixed pluck.

Comment: Wouldnt this attempt to pluck `cars.id` and `cars.email` not `owners.*`.

Answer (score 0):

You should also use `distinct` to avoid users that have multiple cars to be listed multiple times:

```
Car.where(condition: 'something').
   joins(:owner).
   pluck('DISTINCT owners.id, owners.email')
```